# C++ Function for displaying matrix elements showing garbage values

Tags: c++, function

After a long time, I've back to coding and was just brushing out my skills with this simple problem to display diagonal sum of a matrix. While I managed to extract the matrix elements into int array via "getMatrix" function, the another one "showMatrix" is showing garbage values. Where's the error?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i,j;
void getMatrix(int M[100][100])
{
 for(int a=1;a<=i;a++)
  {
    for(int b=1;b<=j;b++) cin>>M[a][b];
  }
}
-------------------------this function----------------------------------------
void showMatrix(int M[100][100])
{
 for(int a=1;a<=i;a++)
  {
    cout<<endl;
    for(int b=1;b<=j;b++) cout<<M[a][b]<<cout<<" ";
  }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
int sum=0;
int m[100][100];
cout<<"Enter matrix dimensions";
cin>>i>>j;
cout<<"Enter Matrix elements\n";
getMatrix(m);
cout<<"Matrix is : ";
showMatrix(m);
for(int n=0;n<=i;n++)sum+=m[n][n];
cout<<"\n sum of diagonal elements is "<<sum;
}
```

If I input 1 2 3 4 it should be displayed as
1 2
3 4 in matrix style
but instead, its showing
10x4c6864 20x4c6864
30x4c6864 40x4c6864 in matrix style.

Comment: Array indices start at 0.

Comment: In your functions, you should pass the `i` and `j` variables as parameters.  Don't rely on global variables because many functions have access to them and can change them (and the order may not be defined the way *you* intend).

Comment: A good coding convention is to always use `{` and `}`, regardless of the number of statements.  Makes maintenance a lot easier.

Comment: Definitely check the dimensions after input (**don't trust the User**).  If the array size is beyond 100, undefined behavior starts.

Comment: See also `std::vector` and `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`.

Comment: Usually, `for` loops are `for (int n = 0; n < i; ++n)`, note the `n < i`, because `array[i]` where `i` is the capacity, is out of bounds.  Arrays are `0 .. (i - 1)` in range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(int b=1;b<=j;b++) cout<<M[a][b]<<cout<<" ";
```

here you print to stdout: the value M[a][b] and the pointer to cout.
That is why you get "garbage values" (0x4c6864) which are pointer addresses.
The correct for loop would be:

```
for(int b=1;b<=j;b++) cout<<M[a][b]<<" ";
```

Also in your sum *n* starts at 0, while in show/getMatrix a starts at 1

```
for(int n=0;n<=i;n++)sum+=m[n][n];
```